# Evaluation summary of many forecasts

Tags: time-series, forecasting, metric, model-evaluation

I predict sales for a 1000 products. I use [time series cross validation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/268847/49821) to evaluate forecast for each product.

I want to report how well the model is performing over the whole product range. Thus, the ideal summary would be 1-3 numbers that are easy to interpret.

Product sales vary significantly. Some product are fast sellers with many sales per day. While others are very slow sellers - zero sales for periods of time.

I looked at:

- [MAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_error), but it suffers from different scales,
- [MAPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_percentage_error), but it's unstable for slow sellers,
- [MASE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_scaled_error), but it's hard to interpret and I'm not sure if I can aggregate it.

What metric would be best to capture an overall performance of the model? Or should I split data into fast/medium/slow sellers?

Answer (score 2):

I would use a weighted MAE and I would add "missed sale opportunity" if item wasn't present or "unnecessary expenses" if it was there and it wasn't bought for a certain period of time.

Basically, use wasted money as a cost/error function.