# How are cross validation and i.i.d. assumption of of a dataset related?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cross-validation, iid

Is it necessary for the observations of the data set to be IID in order to use cross-validation on it? If so, why ? Could you explain in the context of a classification using decision tree.

Comment: features or the samples?

Comment: @gunes I mean the samples / rows of a data set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the typical cross validation assumes iid samples, so that it can freely split the data into training and validation. In case of dependency, such as the temporal dependency in *time series* datasets, modifications respecting this dependency should be done for the splitting of data. Otherwise, there will be *data leakage*. See the following for an example of validation in non iid case: [time series cross validation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14099/using-k-fold-cross-validation-for-time-series-model-selection).