# Cross Validation for longitudinal/panel data in scikit-learn

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, panel-data, scikit-learn

I have some longitudinal/panel data that takes the form below (code for data entry is below the question). Observations of X and y are indexed by time and country (eg USA at time 1, USA at time 2, CAN at time 1).

```
    time x  y
USA 1    5  10
USA 2    5  12
USA 3    6  13
CAN 1    2  2
CAN 2    2  3
CAN 3    4  5
```

I'm trying to predict `y` using sklearn. For a reproducible example, we could use, say, linear regression.

In order to perform CV, I can't use `test_train_split` because then the split might, for example, put data from `time = 3` in `X_train`, and data from `time = 2` into `y_test`. This would be unhelpful, because at `time = 2`, when we would be trying to predict `y`, we would not yet really have data at `time = 3` to train on.

I'm trying to use `TimeSeriesSplit` in order to achieve CV as shown in this image:

[image]
(source: [Using k-fold cross-validation for time-series model selection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14099/using-k-fold-cross-validation-for-time-series-model-selection))

```
y = df.y
X = df.drop(['y'], 1)
print(y)
print(X)
```

```
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit

X = X.to_numpy()

from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit
tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits = 2, max_train_size=3)
print(tscv)
for train_index, test_index in tscv.split(X):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

which gives close to what I need, but not quite:

```
TRAIN: [0 1] TEST: [2 3]
TRAIN: [1 2 3] TEST: [4 5]
```

- How can I now use `TimeSeriesSplit` indices to cross-validate a model?

I believe a complication may be that my data isn't strictly time-series: it's not only indexed by `time`, but also by `country`, hence the longitudinal/panel nature of the data.

My desired output is:

1. A series of test and train indices that allow me to perform "walk forward" CV

eg

```
TRAIN: [1] TEST: [2]
TRAIN: [1 2] TEST: [3]
```

2. An `X_train`, `x_test`, `y_test`, `y_train` that are split using the index above, based on the value of `time`, or clarity as to whether I need to do that.
3. An accuracy score of any model (eg. linear regression) cross-validated using the "walk forward" CV method.

Edit: thank you to @sabacherli for answering the first part of my question, and fixing the errors that were being thrown up.

## Code for Data Entry

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.array([['country','time','x','y'],
                ['USA',1, 5, 10],
                ['USA',2, 5, 12],
                ['USA',3,6, 13],
                ['CAN',1,2, 2],
                ['CAN',2,2, 3],
                ['CAN',3,4, 5]],                
               )
                
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:,1:],
                  index=data[1:,0],
                  columns=data[0,1:])

df
```

Comment: Instead of using sklearn's split, use your own loop using time, and subset your data at each loop (can be optimised later).