# is k-fold cross validation suitable for time series data?

Tags: time-series, cross-validation, svm

I made a prediction model on time series data using the SVR method then to determine the best parameters I used the gridsearch algorithm and k-fold cv using the R software by default. The data that I use for training data is 358 data.
but I want to ask, is k-fold cross validation suitable for time series data?
What is the reason ?
because all this time we know that cross validation takes data randomly while the order of the data in the time series is important.

or should I use another validation method on SVR?
please give me an explanation, thanks.

Comment: [Using k-fold cross-validation for time-series model selection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14099/using-k-fold-cross-validation-for-time-series-model-selection/)

Comment: thank you @user2974951